# How many Rings has each of these Green Lanterns ever held?

Tags: dc, green-lantern

I realize that many Green Lanterns has/have multiple memberships in different color Corps. Can anyone tell me the number of rings (and colors) each one "has ever used" please? Regardless if it was at the same time or a different one.

So to narrow the question down, please list the numbers of membership(s) ever held by the following Green Lanterns please. I am trying to determine who has achieved the most rings.

- Hal Jordan
- Kyle Rayner
- Guy Gardner
- John Stewart
- Alan Scott
- Sinestro
- Abin Sur

Comment: Do you mean "currently possess" or "have ever used"?

Comment: "have ever used"....wanting to know the numbers of rings ever possessed by the following characters:Hal Jordan? Kyle Rayner? Guy Gardner? Jon Stewart? Alan Scott? Sinestro? Thanks, Richard.

Comment: A special case: Mogo has had temporary custody of most of the green rings, to direct them to new recruits.

Answer (score 19):

Kyle Rayner has worn each color of the spectrum and is the White Lantern.

[image: Kyle with each ring]

[image: Rings on the fingers]

Despite the initial shock of being chosen to wield all of the rings after the Green Lanterns were all but destroyed in *Blackest Night*, he learned to wield all of them.

[image: Wielding all]

Comment: Strictly speaking, Kyle only ever actually wore six of the spectrum colors, because the orange ring that "chose" him was fake. But he did eventually learn to wield the Orange Light, alongside all the rest.

Comment: This is possibly the dumbest thing I've ever seen. And I've seen the movie.

Comment: Has Kyle every worn someone else's Green ring?

Comment: @CreationEdge: Considering his ring's duplication function was used to repopulate the GLC, I'm pretty sure he's technically worn EVERYONE'S ring.

Answer (score 6):

As a general rule, each Green Lantern has one green ring.

This is more than just a general rule for the Green Lantern Corps, in fact: with the exception of the Orange Lanterns (all of whom are Ring Constructs of people Larfleeze has killed and/or eaten) each Lantern is a member of a single Corps and has a single ring.

There are very few exceptions:

- Mongul briefly possessed several Yellow Rings, which he thought made him stronger (and given your belief partially powers any ring, may have been true) before he was beaten into the pavement by Sinestro.
- Guy Gardner was once possessed by a Red Ring. It didn't last long, Mogo helped him purge the red energy from his system.
- The Star Sapphires had a habit of kidnapping other ring bearers (especially those with yellow rings) and 'converting' them. They were encased in sapphire and essentially brainwashed to serve as Star Sapphires.  A few of the Sinestro Corps (Yellow Lanterns) converted to Star Sapphires (Violet Lanterns) this way, though they then stopped wearing their Yellow Rings.
- Hal Jordan briefly had a Blue Ring forced upon him. It didn't let go until he had mastered it (by telling it what he hoped for) and then it was released. Hal didn't want the blue ring to start with, and wearing two colored rings interfered with his ability to use either properly.

  [image: Hal has a bad day]
- Hal has also worn a red ring (briefly), it seems:

  [image: Hal as a Red Lantern]

Frankly, I'd be willing to guess that Hal has worn more rings than anyone else, because the War of Light was seen by many writers as a way to dress Hal up in as many costumes as they could.

All of the above happened during the War of Light. Further back in time, Sinestro gave up his Green Ring in favor of the first Yellow Ring (alternatively, as the backstory changes, he was given the boot from the GL Corps and forged the Yellow Ring).

Guy Gardner wore a Yellow Ring for a while, back before he became the Warrior (let's not talk about that, ok?  It was the 90s, it was a bad time). This was the ring he used when he went up against (and was put down by) Doomsday. He couldn't use it very well (he didn't speak the language it used) but he made it work well enough. Batman still put him down with one punch.

Long story short: it isn't common for any Ring-based hero to use more than a single ring at a time, or for them to use rings of different colors simultaneously.

During *Blackest Night*, Black Rings found dead (and later, formerly dead) characters. Many dead Lanterns were risen as Black Lanterns, but they didn't retain any of their former colors.

Comment: Hal's [Green Lantern Wiki page](http://greenlantern.wikia.com/wiki/Hal_Jordan) lists him as a member of the Green Lantern corps, and the former member of *6* other corps. White, Blue, Red, Orange, Black, and Sinestro corps are all listed. Looks like he might be missing Indigo and the Star Sapphires.

Comment: @Ellesedil: Yeah, in Blackest Night he wore White, Blue, Black (I think), and Green at various times.  Not sure when Red happened, but screen above.  That just leaves Orange and Yellow unaccounted for.  Frankly, I'm not surprised - Hal is the first one they put a new outfit on, and him in a different color sells comics.

Comment: In War of the Green Lanterns, Hal actually wields Yellow and Orange *at the same time*, although he had been wielding a Yellow ring for a bit previous. Here's a really good summary of the overall story: https://youtu.be/Tjf0qe_-vzY?t=15m27s. In Wrath of the First Lantern, he intentionally wields a black ring: https://youtu.be/fpCHIaagLvI?t=6m38s

Answer (score 5):

### Most colors: Kyle Rayner

As has been mentioned in previous answers, Kyle Rayner has worn a ring of every color of the emotional spectrum and is the only White Lantern (which also encompasses all colors of the spectrum).

[image: Kyle Rayner with all the rings]

### Most rings: Hal Jordan

During the ["Emerald Twilight"](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/emerald-twilight/4045-41289/) storyline, Hal Jordan, enraged by the destruction of Coast City, rampages toward Oa to take revenge on the Guardians. The Guardians send all their best Lanterns to try to stop Hal, but Hal beats them one by one and takes their rings.

This scene shows him wielding ten rings at once:

[image: Emerald Twilight 1]

And this cover art (so, take it for what it's worth) shows him wielding no less than *thirteen*:

[image: Emerald Twilight cover]

Comment: I'd even add that throughout the years, Hal has even wielded his original ring, then another one, then a dupe made by Sinestro when Geoff Johns made him green again, (probably some others in the meantime) and recently built his own ring out of his own pure willpower. So yeah, not only has wielded the most at once, but also the most separated rings.

Answer (score 3):

With the exception of Orange, Black, White, Phantom, and Ultraviolet. Guy Gardner has had them all.

If you consider the Phantom Ring (from the Rebirth issue *Green Lanterns* #10) to count as every ring (when using the Phantom Ring, the possessor is able to use the powers of any color, cycling through them based on what they're feeling) Simon Baz would've had possession of the most rings as he is the only Green Lantern to date to use the Phantom Ring.

[image: Guy and Bleez talk about Blue Lanterns]

Comment: I don't see how the comic page relates to the text.  This may just be an ordering issue: If it just relates to the first sentence, then you ought to put the part about the Phantom ring after the image.

Comment: Jessica used the Phantom Ring as well.

Answer (score 1):

Going strictly by the list of characters given in the question, and the known ring colors, which as of February 2020 are Red, Orange, Yellow, Green, Blue, Indigo, Violet, Black, White, Phantom and Ultraviolet. The last two have been introduced recently, Phantom in DC Rebirth's *Green Lanterns* and Ultraviolet in *Justice League* (2018 run).

*For the sake of readability, all panels are linked to but not included, as it would distort the bullet list.*

## Hal Jordan

- Green (obviously)
- Red (*Green Lantern* #38, 2009 and *Injustice 2* #55, 2018)
- Blue (*Green Lantern* #38 as well, lasted for a couple issues)
- Yellow (pretty often actually, the most recent ones being, I think, the Krona war in 2011 and *Injustice*, both game and comics)
- Orange (during the Krona war in 2011, [dual-wielding with Yellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTAm5.jpg) in *Emerald Warriors* #10)
- [Black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoUZv.jpg) (*Green Lantern* #20, 2013, in Geoff Johns' final Green Lantern issue)
- [White](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zm0HB.jpg) (*Blackest Night* #8, 2010), not the same kind of White Lantern that Kyle is
- basically, every ring except Indigo, Phantom and Ultraviolet.

## Kyle Rayner

- Red, Orange, Yellow, Green, Blue, Indigo, Violet, White (see panels in other answers; it would be redundant to nclude them again)
- has never worn Black, Phantom and Ultraviolet.

## Guy Gardner

- Green
- Red (many times, notably became leader of the Red Lanterns in the run of the same name)
- Violet (in *Emerald Warriors* #10, [dual-wielding with Red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTAm5.jpg))
- [Blue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQUd8.jpg) (*Red Lanterns: Futures End*, 2014)
- Guy claims to have worn Indigo in the panel above. As far as I know, this is part of the five-years time jump from the *Futures End* arc, because I don't remember ever reading that elsewhere and I can't find references to it.
- the same could be said for Yellow, although Guy wore a Yellow Ring back in *Guy Gardner Reborn* #3 (1992); but the Yellow Ring he dons in the *Futures End* panel indicates he wore one of the current Sinestro Rings.
- has never worn Orange, Black, White, Phantom or Ultraviolet.

## John Stewart

- Green
- [Indigo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWbb7.jpg) (*Green Lantern* #65 and the rest of the Krona war, 2011); even became temporary leader of the Indigo Tribe in *Green Lantern Corps: Futures End* (2014)
- (kind of) Black, channeling it through the Indigo Light (*Green Lantern Corps* #60)
- [Violet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQpWY.jpg) in *Green Lantern Corps* #36 (2015); first ever male Star Sapphire (Guy does not count as the ring did not actually choose him)
- [Ultraviolet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joRXf.jpg) in *Justice League* #3 (2018)
- has never worn Red, Orange, Yellow, Blue, Black, White or Phantom.

## Alan Scott

- Green, though technically it shouldn't count, as Alan Scott's Green Ring is magic and not part of the regular Green Lantern Corps.
- none of the others.

## Sinestro

- Green
- Yellow
- [White](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLMOG.jpg) in *Blackest Night* #7 (2010), not the same kind of White Lantern that Kyle is
- [Black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04xAi.jpg), although not in the main universe; he got it in the Dark Multiverse, after his actions as White Lantern in this universe lead to the Black Lanterns winning the Blackest Night (*Tales From the Dark Multiverse: Blackest Night*, 2019)
- [Indigo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJk8I.jpg) when he was kidnapped and brainwashed by the Indigo Tribe in *Green Lantern* #8 (2012)
- [Ultraviolet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joRXf.jpg) in *Justice League* #3 (2018)
- has never worn Red, Orange, Blue, Violet or Phantom.

## Abin Sur

- Green
- [Black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDcmZ.jpg) during the *Blackest Night* arc (*Green Lantern* #46, 2009)
- [White](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4n0a.jpg) in the Flashpoint universe (*Flashpoint: Abin Sur - The Green Lantern* #3, 2011)
- has never worn Red, Orange, Yellow, Blue, Indigo, Violet, Phantom or Ultraviolet.